# Generally is floor(x) or mod(x,y) (modulo function) used more in maths?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know these functions are interrelated cause

$mod(x,1)+floor(x)= x$

And I think they're pretty cool functions but I don't see them used much at all in maths.

I guess mod is used in number theory but i never see it anywhere else.

So I asked this question.

Comment: I mean they're valid mathematical functions. There are certainly places in math where they're very useful. At least in some parts of the world, I know that when doing math its common to use a less wordy and more compact math-y notation such as $\lfloor x\rfloor$

Comment: i saw that notation for floor(x) but how you do you type it?

Comment: \$\lfloor x\rfloor\$

Comment: To answer your general question, mods are very, very useful, while the floor function is useful. In some sense, the generalization of mods (the notion of quotient objects) is everywhere in mathematics.

Comment: Modulo and floor for real numbers are used quite often. Modulo for integers is used extremely often, in group theory, in cryptography.